# 'Remove middleman' IntelliJ refactoring on an empty interface

Tags: java, refactoring, interface, intellij-idea

I have an interface which is now empty, and extends another interface. I'd like to remove the empty interface and use the base interface, and am trying to find the correct refactoring in IntelliJ.

I've tried "remove middleman" but got "cannot perform the refactoring. The caret should be positioned at the name of the field to be refactored".

Answer (score 6):

I think what you want to do is the "inline" refactor on the unwanted interface, e.g.

If

```
 
class Thing implements ThingA
```

and

```
interface ThingA extends ThingB
```

To get rid of `ThingA`

you do and inline (<kbd>ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>alt</kbd> + <kbd>n</kbd>) when the caret is on `ThingA`, you end up with:

```
class Thing implements ThingB
```

Answer (score 2):

I think that what you're looking for is the "Type Migration" refactoring.

Comment: Not working - I still get "The caret should be positioned..." error.

Comment: Where are you applying the refactor ? This refactor has to be applied in the class of the field declaration. So if you have:
A extends B
....
private A myField;

you can only apply this refactoring on A in the field declaration line.

Answer (score 2):

Looking at [a blog post explaining the "Remove Middleman" refactoring](http://blogs.jetbrains.com/idea/2008/12/intellij-idea-8-refactorings-remove-middleman/) in IDEA, I'd think you simply cannot use it for this. It's just for "replacing all calls to delegating methods with the equivalent direct calls".

(For a moment I thought another refactoring, "Use Interface Where Possible", might be of help, but I couldn't get that working either in my simple test case.)

Answer (score 0):

The best way to remove uses of an empty interface is through "Use interface where possible", go to the definition of the interface you want to remove and select "Use interface where possible" from the "Refactor" menu. You should then end up with an unused interface which you can safely delete.